# Passing parameter into Spring factory bean factory method

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, factory-method

I have a `Spring` bean which is declared like this:

```
<osgi:reference id="basicAuthSecurityHandler" interface="com.groupgti.handler.authentication.basic.Handler"/>
<bean id="securityHandler" factory-bean="basicAuthSecurityHandler" factory-method="getSecurityHandler"/>
```

My `getSecurityHandler` method looks like this:

```
public ConstraintSecurityHandler getSecurityHandler(String realm) {
    ConstraintSecurityHandler handler =(ConstraintSecurityHandler) factory.getBean("securityHandler");
    handler.setRealmName(realm);
    return handler;
}
```

This `securityHandler` bean is in scope `prototype`. I need to pass the parameter into `getSecurityHandler` method when it it constructed with spring. Is this even possible? I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I got it working is this:

```
<osgi:reference id="basicAuthSecurityHandler" interface="com.groupgti.handler.authentication.basic.Handler"/>

<bean id="securityHandler" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="basicAuthSecurityHandler"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="getSecurityHandler"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value type="java.lang.String">${com.groupgti.esb.targetjobs.indeed.userRealm}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I had to use `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`. I have tried to use `constructor-arg`, but then I got the exception that there is no such constructor. Using `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of Spring it was possible to do this using constructor-arg>. See docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/beans.html). You can probably still do that. Haven't tried it!

Comment: also check this blog post from spring team: http://blog.springsource.org/2011/08/09/whats-a-factorybean/

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446230/how-to-inject-spring-bean-for-factory-method-requiring-myclass-class-parameter