# How to inject Spring Bean for factory method requiring MyClass.class parameter

Tags: java, spring, class, preferences, factory

I'm trying to inject a java.util.prefs.Preferences bean in to my master controller. The controller looks like:

```
@Controller
class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private Preferences preferences;
}
```

The application-context.xml file creates the bean for java.util.prefs.Preferences. It uses a factory method so I have the following entry for creating the bean:

```
<bean id="preferences" class="java.util.prefs.Preferences" factory-method="userNodeForPackage" />
```

Preferences.userNodeForPackage(param) takes for a parameter the class related to the Preference. In this case Spring needs to create the bean by performing the call:

```
Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MyController.class);
```

How can a class be passed in to a spring bean instantiated with a factory method?
Thanks

Environment information:

```
Java 7
Spring 3.1
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can specify the `constructor-arg` element

```
<bean id="preferences" class="java.util.prefs.Preferences" factory-method="userNodeForPackage">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class" value="com.path.MyController" />
</bean>
```

This is explained in the official documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-some-examples), section 5.4.1.

> Arguments to the static factory method are supplied via
>    elements, exactly the same as if a constructor had
>   actually been used. The type of the class being returned by the
>   factory method does not have to be of the same type as the class that
>   contains the static factory method, although in this example it is. An
>   instance (non-static) factory method would be used in an essentially
>   identical fashion (aside from the use of the factory-bean attribute
>   instead of the class attribute), so details will not be discussed
>   here.

Comment: He needs to provide argument as parameter to `userNodeForPackage()` method, not constructor of `Preferences`

Comment: @NandkumarTekale Read the quote and the documentation. That's how you do it when you've specified `factory-method` attribute.

Comment: This technique also works to use a static field value as a constructor argument!

Answer (score 3):

Well I don't know the xml based configuration way but I can tell you how you can instantiate it via `Configuration` class.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean(name="preferences")
    public java.util.prefs.Preferences preferences() {
        // init
        return java.util.prefs.Preferences.userNodeForPackage(YourExpectedClass.class);
    }
}
```

P.S. :

You will need to add your configuration class/package for scanning either in web.xml if you are using complete annotation based approach `[contextClass=org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext]` or in your config file as below :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.comp.prod.conf" />
```

Comment: +1 Should probably mention in your answer it comes from the spring-context artifact in Maven.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public class Preferences
 {  
     SomeBean someBean;

     public void setSomeBean(SomeBean someBean){
            this.someBean = someBean;
     }  

     public static Preferences createSampleBeanWithIntValue(SomeBean someBean)
     {
         Preferences preferences= new Preferences();
         preferences.setSomeBean(someBean);
         return preferences;
     }
}

  <bean id="someBean" class="java.util.prefs.SomeBean"/>

 <bean id="preferences" class="java.util.prefs.Preferences" factory-method="userNodeForPackage" > 

    <constructor-arg ref="someBean "/>       
 </bean>
```

Please see the reference

http://www.skorks.com/2008/10/are-you-using-the-full-power-of-spring-when-injecting-your-dependencies/

Answer (score 0):

first create the bean of 'Preferences' class either using xml file or using annotation.
then 
you can use this `<context:annotation-config>`  if you created bean using   xml configuration to activate the @Autowired annotation functionality
 (or )

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.estudo.controller" />`
if you created bean using annotations.
Note : define the above tags in the spring servlet xml file

Answer (score 0):

Spring framework provides facility to inject bean using factory method. To do so, we can use two attributes of bean element.

factory-method: represents the factory method that will be invoked to inject the bean.
factory-bean: represents the reference of the bean by which factory method will be invoked. It is used if factory method is non-static.
A method that returns instance of a class is called factory method.

```
public class A {  
public static A getA(){//factory method  
    return new A();  
}  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try making "preferences" a property of "MyController".
Something like

```
<bean id="MyController" class="com.your.package.MyController">
    <property name="preferences" ref="preferences" />
</bean>
```

and then have the getter and setter method for preferences in MyController.

I think this should work.

Comment: OP's problem isn't autowiring the object. The problem is specifying and argument to a static factory-method.